# Understanding homebrew's python formulae for different versions and setting default

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I have multiple versions (formulae) of python installed using homebrew on my macOS Monterey system, that in the past I never bothered exploring.

When I execute the following command,

```
brew search '/^python$|^python@/'
```

I get

```
python@3.10, python@3.7, python@3.8, python@3.9
```

**Note:** The default python formula that homebrew provides using the     `brew install python` command is `python@3.9`. Since I wanted to    use the latest version i.e. 3.10, I had installed it using the more verbose command: `brew install python@3.10`.

Looking at the output of `brew info python@3.X`, I find that

- For X=10, it's `bottled`, `keg-only` and installed
- For X=9, it's `bottled` and installed
- For X=8, it's `bottled`, `keg-only` but is not installed
- For X=7, it's `keg-only` and is not not installed

Also, `python3 --version` returns *Python 3.9.9*.

So it looks like `homebrew-core` has `python@3.9` as it's default.

I now want to choose `python@3.10` as my default. The usual process of unlinking 3.9 (`brew unlink python@3.9`) and relinking (`brew link python@3.10`) helps with exposing python@3.10 to the path, but seems ad-hoc.

For example, `brew doctor` complains that `python@3.9` is not exposed since `python@3.9` is present in `homebrew-core` and not `python@3.10`.

**Question:**

Can I make `python@3.10` my default in a clean way? Does it mean I have to add `python@3.10` and remove `python@3.9` from *homebrew-core/Formula*? (potentially conflicting with the main git branch) Also, why is `python@3.10` not the default in the first place when a stable version is available?

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, Homebrew's intended use of the `python` formulae is a bit confusing. See the article ["Homebrew Python Is Not For You"](https://justinmayer.com/posts/homebrew-python-is-not-for-you/):

> Homebrew’s Python is not for you. It exists to serve Homebrew, or more accurately, Homebrew’s other formulae. The primary purpose of Homebrew’s Python formula is to enable other Python-dependent Homebrew packages to work. If installing Homebrew’s Python allows you to run the occasional Python script or access the REPL, that’s a nice side benefit, but anything beyond that — including developing software with Python — is squarely out-of-scope.

> There are several solutions that put you back in control of when Python versions are installed, upgraded, and removed. Personally, I use asdf and its Python plugin to do just that. I prefer asdf to similar tools such as Pyenv and Pythonz because not only can you install multiple Python versions but also multiple Node.js versions, Ruby versions, and many more.

As the author alludes, this also applies to other Homebrew formulae such as `ruby`. For that, I use `rbenv` to manage my own Ruby installations.